# Why git commit can be lost in this case?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, git-reflog, reflog

My colleague did a series of careless pull/push operations. He end up in a situation where his local commit becomes missing

I recovered his commit using `git reflog`. But I couldn't figure out why his operations lead to the situation. Can someone shed some lights?

See `git reflog` output and comments below:

```
#######
# reflog is in reverse manner, most recent operation first
# test is like our "develop" branch, MTX-65 is the feature branch
# Both are remote-tracking
#######
39261b7 (HEAD -> MTX-65, origin/feature/MTX-65) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from test to MTX-65
7f66c72 (test) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from MTX-65 to test
39261b7 (HEAD -> MTX-65, origin/feature/MTX-65) HEAD@{2}: pull: Fast-forward
d51c1be HEAD@{3}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/MTX-65
d51c1be HEAD@{4}: rebase: Add Notification
c33d31f HEAD@{5}: pull --tags -r origin feature/MTX-65: checkout c33d31f4d0109396dea6d6bb78f47ba56097e4ac

#######
# This is the key commit that got lost
# It's not in `git log` out any more
#######
a6a7a7e HEAD@{6}: commit (merge): Warning message
3c8113c HEAD@{7}: commit (amend): Add Notification
7f551e4 HEAD@{8}: commit: Add Notification
96bcf99 HEAD@{9}: pull --tags -r origin feature/MTX-65: Fast-forward
b79bee0 HEAD@{10}: commit: personal & institution page
3cfb1aa HEAD@{11}: commit: Institution：
7f66c72 (test) HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from test to MTX-65
7f66c72 (test) HEAD@{13}: merge MTX-65: Fast-forward
0733fd2 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from MTX-65 to test
7f66c72 (test) HEAD@{15}: commit (merge): Merge test
ebfaeea HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from test to MTX-65
0733fd2 HEAD@{17}: pull: Fast-forward
1043c35 HEAD@{18}: checkout: moving from MTX-65 to test

#######
# This is a commit that still exists after the disaster
#######
ebfaeea HEAD@{19}: commit: institution 认证信息
```

Comment: If the lost commit is `a6a7a7e`, it is dropped during `git rebase` without `-p` because it's a merge commit.

Comment: @ElpieKay My understanding is that most merge commit has a message in the form of "Merged XXX into branch YYY". `a6a7a7e` doesn't. Any reasons? Also what is the mechanism and why `rebase` would drop merge commits by default? Would you live to elaborate into an answer post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at `a6a7a7e HEAD@{6}: commit (merge): Warning message`.

`commit (merge)` indicates the merge encounters conflicts. After resolving conflicts, your colleague changes the default commit message to `Warning message`. The default message is like `Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy`.

Then your colleague runs `git pull --tags -r origin feature/MTX-65`. With `-r`, `git rebase` is used instead of `git merge` after the fetch is done.

As the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins) says,

> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo
>   list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch.

There are many debates about which is better, `git merge` or `git rebase`. One of the pros for `git rebase` is that we can use it to create a linear history in a convenient way. As designed, merge commits are dropped by default, although `git rebase` provides `-r` and `-p` to preserve them in some situations.

During `git rebase`, the conflicts are expected to occur again. In theory, the changes can't be lost if your colleague resolves them the same way as he does in the previous `git merge`. You can try `git log --reflog -S <keywords> -p` to find out in which commit the changes including the keywords get lost.